# Achieving best timing online for psychophysics experiments using Python on the web

Tags: python, web, fastcgi, timing, psychtoolbox

I want to display visual/auditory stimuli inside a web browser for psychophysic experiments. I plan on using python, but I am concerned with timing. I obviously can not rely on screen refresh for timing which is common in these types of tasks. How much can I hope for in terms of accuracy for timing on the web and what are the best tools to use with Python. I am thinking of using FastCGI

I just want to hear peoples thoughts on this.

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by "timing?"

Comment: @MattBall, I think shameh is doing something akin to an [Implicit Association Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_Association_Test) which requires measuring, with a fair bit of precision, a subject's reaction time. shameh, this is a good question but I think you should add some more detail, especially if my guess is wrong.

Comment: Javascript would probably be more suited for this.

Comment: I suggest a Python backend serving HTML5, which is perfect for the visual, user-responsive applications I imagine you are describing.

Comment: @senderle Not exclusively, there will be others such as reading etc. There could be input but ultimately I want to match it up with EEG data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your timing in JS, save current time in ms on document.ready and then when user hits a key.

Benchmark your test with either

- high-speed camera, or
- test rig that "hits" a key, e.g. screen flash -> pohototransistor -> usb device -> virtual keyboard